# Edit CSS of text that has no class or id

Tags: html, css

This seems like it should be simple enough, but **using pure CSS** how could I edit a line of text (in this case printed by a script) that has no html tag, CSS class or id?

This is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div class="price">
    <h4>
       <span class="amount">
           <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
           18.06
       </span>
       <!--EDIT THIS LINE -->  &nbsp;(as of Nov 1, 2017, 1:37 am)                   
    </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: What is it you want to edit exactly? colour? font-size?

Comment: Font size in this case

Comment: Ok so substitute the `color: red;` and `color: green;` rules in my answer with `font-size: /* your font size */;`

Comment: The only way to do that would be to style the `h4` with your desired font size and then undo that same styling for `span.amount`.    Better, if possible, to wrap the script's output in a tag before inserting it into the DOM, so you have something more specific to target with your CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the properties of the text without editing the actual text itself if that's what you're looking for? Whatever you set for `h4`, counteract it with `h4 span.amount`, like so:

```
h4 {
   color: green;
}

h4 span.amount {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You need a selector to apply css property. 
But there is is an another to do this but this is not the smart way. See the following example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</body>
</html>
<style type="text/css">
    *{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text is enclosed in the `h4` tag which itself is inclose in `div.price`.

So if you do not wish to put a default style on the `html` or `body` tag, you could use

```
.price > h4 {
    /* style for text in <h4> */
}
.amount {
    /* different style for text in the <span>, if required */
}
```